# mapping intensity from dot product to float RGB 0->1

Tags: c, graphics, rendering

I'm getting the dot product of the surface normal and light position. The weird thing is the dot product is larger than 1. That's problem number 1.

The second problem is I want to map that intensity from 0->1 to Float RGB from 0->1
here is my code

```
    if (the_object->polys[curr_poly].shading == 1)
            {

                // compute the dot product between the light source vector
                // and normal vector to surface

                dp = Dot_Product_3D((vector_3d_ptr)&normal,
                    (vector_3d_ptr)&light_source);

                // test if light ray is reflecting off surface

                if (dp > 0)
                {
                    // now cos 0 = (u.v)/|u||v| or

                    intensity = ambient_light + ( dp / (the_object->polys[curr_poly].normal_length));


                    float r = the_object->polys[curr_poly].color.R*intensity;
                    float g = the_object->polys[curr_poly].color.G*intensity;
                    float b = the_object->polys[curr_poly].color.B*intensity;
                    Color color = Color(r, g, b, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you understand what scalar products are, in any case they are `|a|*|b|*cos Θ`. they could certainly be over or under 1 since cos Θ is at most 1, multiplying the vectors, unless they are unit vectors may certainly lead to various numbers.

also, to map between intensity to RGB, (if RGB is in standard 0-255 range), multiplying it won't help you much, you need to normalize it between the range, like this:

`(color / 255) * intensity`

you could also clamp the color between the values so you don't get overexposure or the likes.

please clarify further the issues if this does not help. (I can't comment yet so I answered as much as I could).

Comment: The RGB value is in the range of 0 >1, for example RGB (1,0,0) is all red

Comment: can you please explain what do you mean by mapping intensity to color? adjust color according to intensity? to reflect lighting cast on the object?

Comment: yes that's what I mean. I'm doing flat shading using software rasterizer, so I have light vector and face normal, and I'm calculating the dot product to modulate the model color

Comment: so your intensity should be greater than 1 if it's bright enough and lesser than if dark enough to affect the color. assuming that you calculate the intensity correctly that should work. what is the light source vector? what does it represent?

Comment: it's a normalized light vector, the light source vector

Comment: here is the full code and video http://pastebin.com/ki8ae1aM   https://youtu.be/siksvA1jgeY